# Performing different tasks by holding text view using touch listener

Tags: java, android, textview, touch-event

I have a text view, on which I am implementing the touch listener.

**Code:**

```
 textview_temp2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                  
                  switch(motionEvent.getAction())
                  {
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                          Log.i("TAG1","touched Down");
                          
                          return  true;
                     
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                          Log.i("TAG3","touched UP");
                          return  true;

                  }
                  return false;
              }
          });
```

Now, I want to call event action up if the user holds the text view for 5 or more seconds. Also, only one among these two events should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to accomplish. You need to use a handler to handle your delayed tasks.

```
final int STEP3SECS = 3;
final int STEP5SECS = 5;
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == STEP3SECS) {
            //do 3 second job
        } else if (msg.what == STEP5SECS) {
            //do 5 second job
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

And then:

```
textview_temp2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        switch(motionEvent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                Log.i("TAG1","touched Down");
                handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(STEP3SECS,3000);
                handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(STEP5SECS,5000);
                return  true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                Log.i("TAG3","touched UP");
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                return  true;

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

`ACTION_UP` can take place in 3 different time intervals: before 3 seconds, well no job gets done. After 3 seconds and before 5 seconds, only 3 second job gets done. And after 5 seconds which both jobs are handled.

Answer (score 1):

Save the system time when touched down, then at touched up compare how much time elapsed. Anything between 3-5 seconds you execute the 3 second action, anything above the 5 second you execute the 5 seconds action. If you want to automatically do the 5 second action at 5 seconds even if the user keep the touch down, then you could use a timer with a 5 seconds duration, you start the timer on initial touch down and stop it on touched up. The timer should call the same method/action you want for the 5 seconds if it ticks down to 0 without being stopped by a touched up.